# Choosing corner values for trilinear interpolation

Tags: interpolation, sampling, volumetric

I'm caching distances for SDF functions in volume textures for faster rendering, and I'd like to use trilinear interpolation for smoother edges. I know that I'll need distance values at each corner; can I blend adjacent voxels, or will I need to store eight separate distances in each sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, SDFs do much better under interpolation than regular images do—it’s why you can mostly get away with using tiny textures for e.g. font data. You should be fine interpolating neighboring voxels.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I expect to have up to ~30 high-resolution volumes in memory at once so keeping them all as small as possible is important; interpolating between neighbour voxels instead of local corners should make that much easier.